# How to avoid the horizontal separator while using multirow?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, ieeetran, multirow, ieee-style

Creating a table in IEEE transaction format. The last cell of the table has to combine two rows. I can put the same text using the multirow package, but the horizontal separator cuts right through the text. Here is my code for the table.

```
\begin{table*}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[l]{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\textbf{Description} & \textbf{Constraints} & \textbf{Objective} &\textbf{Remarks}\\
\hline
Sum rate maximisation with given sum power&$\sum_{i=1}^Kp_i$&$\sum_{i=1}^Kr_i$&Solved~\cite{Barman2014a}\\      \hline
Sum power minimisation with given sum rate&$\sum_{i=1}^Kr_i$&$\sum_{i=1}^Kp_i$&Proposed here\\ \hline
Weighted rate maximisation with individual power constraints&$p_i\leq p'_i\quad\forall i$&$\sum_{i=1}^Kw_ir_i$&Solved~\cite{Tse1998}\\
\hline
Sum power minimisation with individual rate constraints&$r_i\leq r'_i\quad\forall i$&$\sum_{i=1}^Kp_i$&Sub-optimal solution proposed~\cite{Yu2006}\\
\hline
Weighted sum power minimisation with individual rate constraints&$r_i\leq r'_i\quad\forall i$&$\sum_{i=1}^K\lambda_ip_i$&Not solved\\
\hline
Weighted sum power minimisation with weighted rate constraint&$\sum_{i=1}^Kw_ir_i$&$\sum_{i=1}^K\lambda_ip_i$&\multirow{2}{*}{Standard convex problem}\\
\hline
Weighted sum rate maxisation with target weighted power constraint&$\sum_{i=1}^K\lambda_ip_i$&$\sum_{i=1}^Kw_ir_i$&\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

And here is my output table. [image: output table]
As you can see the problem is with the "Standard convex problem". How to make the line stop at the previous column. Also please tell me how to post a large block of code here with proper tabulation. I cannot format it correctly. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Instead of `\hline` use `\cline{1-3}` for example.

Comment: Please also consider adding some struts to give the taller math expressions some room to breathe.

Comment: Also, I'd advise getting rid of the vertical lines, you don't need them. Align the content to (l)eft, and it'll make natural "vertical rules".